# Delete until given character starting from given string

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

```
root@server:~/foo$ cat INPUT.txt
limit. Current u'^'ZO
limit. Current usage'^'FR
limit. Current us'^'AS
limit. Current usage 95 %.'^'FR
limit. Cur'^'AEW
root@server:~/foo$ sed "s/limit.SOMEMAGIC/limit./g" INPUT.txt
limit.'^'ZO
limit.'^'FR
limit.'^'AS
limit.'^'FR
limit.'^'AEW
```

**Question:** how can we delete the strings (" Cur......") after "limit." until the: " ' " ? Searching for "SOMEMAGIC" :)

Comment: Don't be root: Use a tool such as `sudo` so you don't have to be logged in as root. Else one day you will cut your own foot off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the specific input you show, you could simply do

```
perl -pe "s/ Cur[^']*//" INPUT.txt
```

or, in `sed`

```
sed "s/ Cur[^']*//" INPUT.txt
```

These will simply delete a space followed by `Cur` and as many non-`'` characters as possible. If you need to do this *only* if the previous word was `limit.`, use one of the other answers or:

```
awk "\$1~/limit\./{sub(/Cur[^']*/,\"\",\$2)}1;" INPUT.txt
```

There are some quoting acrobatics going on there because we need to enclose the awk scriptlet in `"` because we need the `[^']` so the shell will expand `$1` and `$2` before they are passed to awk unless we escape them as `\$1` and `\$2`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
sed -e "s/^\(limit\.\)[^']*/\1/" < data
```

This matches `limit.` at the start of a line, followed by as many characters as possible [that aren't `'`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05), and replaces it with just the part at the start (`\1`). You can edit the pattern and the replacement according to how your data actually is - the important part is `[^']*`.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` (version > 5.10.0):

```
$ perl -pe "s/^limit\.\K(.*?)\'/\'/" file
limit.'^'ZO
limit.'^'FR
limit.'^'AS
limit.'^'FR
limit.'^'AEW
```

From `perldoc perlrebackslash`:

```
\K  This appeared in perl 5.10.0. Anything matched left of "\K" is not
    included in $&, and will not be replaced if the pattern is used in a
    substitution. This lets you write "s/PAT1 \K PAT2/REPL/x" instead of
    "s/(PAT1) PAT2/${1}REPL/x" or "s/(?<=PAT1) PAT2/REPL/x".

    Mnemonic: Keep.
```